# Webpack 2/Gulp/Typescript generating unexpected token error

Tags: typescript, gulp, webpack-2

I'm trying to update a project that was using webpack 1 to now use webpack 2 and I'm getting two different issues that I can't get around.

The first issue is that webpack can't seem to locate my entry point unless I provide '' as an option in the resolve extensions array - based on my understanding of the docs this shouldn't be necessary anymore with webpack 2. I can get around the error by adding '' but then I get an error with attempting to load the file ("Unexpected token. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type"). I only include both issues in this post as I think they may be both symptoms of the same problem.

Here's a portion of my gulp file that I'm using:

```
const helpers = require('./config/helpers');

var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackStream = require('webpack-stream');

const buildNumber = process.env.buildNumber = helpers.buildNumber;


gulp.task('build-host-Debug', function (cb) {
    var webpackConfig_Host = require('./config/webpack-host.dev.js');

    return gulp
        .src([
            './src/app/entry1.ts'
        ], { base: 'src' })
        .pipe(webpackStream(webpackConfig_Host))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'));
});
```

I split the webpack config into two files - here's the common file which includes the typescript loader:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var helpers = require('./helpers');
var Visualizer = require('webpack-visualizer-plugin');

require('es6-promise').polyfill();

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        MyEntry1: './src/app/entry1.ts',
        MyEntry2: './src/app/entry2.ts'
    },
    output: {
        path: helpers.root('app'),
        filename: 'js/[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.tsx', '.ts', '.js'] 
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'app/management'), helpers.root('src', 'app/main'), /node_modules/],
                use: [{
                    loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'app/management'), helpers.root('src', 'app/main'), /node_modules/],
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader?name=images/[name].[ext]'
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new Visualizer({
            filename: './stats-host.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

And this is the inherited file that has the development specific stuff (as opposed to my production file which is slightly different):

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack-host.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

process.env.buildNumber = helpers.buildNumber;

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /entry1\.scss$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'app/css'),
                use: [{ loader: 'file-loader?name=css/[name].css' }, { loader: 'sass-loader?sourceMap' }]
            },
            {
                test: /entry2\.scss$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'app/css'),
                use: [{ loader: 'file-loader?name=css/[name].css' }, { loader: 'sass-loader?sourceMap' }]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'buildNumber': JSON.stringify(process.env.buildNumber)
            }
        })
    ]
});
```

If I remove the '' from the resolved extensions then I get this error:

```
Error: Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./src/app/entry1.ts in W:\TestApp\
resolve file
  W:\TestApp\src\app\entry1.ts.tsx doesn't exist
  W:\TestApp\src\app\entry1.ts.ts doesn't exist
  W:\TestApp\src\app\entry1.ts.js doesn't exist
resolve directory
  W:\TestApp\src\app\entry1.ts\package.json doesn't exist (directory description file)
  W:\TestApp\src\app\entry1.ts is not a directory
```

If I leave in the '' I get this error:

```
Error: ./src/app/entry1.ts
Module parse failed: W:\TestApp\src\app\entry1.ts Unexpected token (14:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (14:13)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (W:\TestApp\node_modules\webpack-stream\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (W:\TestApp\node_modules\webpack-stream\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (W:\TestApp\node_modules\webpack-stream\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:581:61)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseVarStatement (W:\TestApp\node_modules\webpack-stream\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:918:10)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (W:\TestApp\node_modules\webpack-stream\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:706:19)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (W:\TestApp\node_modules\webpack-stream\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (W:\TestApp\node_modules\webpack-stream\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (W:\TestApp\node_modules\webpack-stream\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (W:\TestApp\node_modules\webpack-stream\node_modules\webpack\lib\Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (W:\TestApp\node_modules\webpack-stream\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:104:16)
```

I appreciate any help that anyone might be able to provide as I'm getting kind of desperate and would rather not have to stay on webpack 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your entry points don't need to have the extension specified:

```
entry: {
    MyEntry1: './src/app/entry1',
    MyEntry2: './src/app/entry2'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My gulp task had to pass in the webpack object to webpackStream:

```
gulp.task('build-host-Debug', function (cb) {
    var webpackConfig_Host = require('./config/webpack-host.dev.js');

    return gulp
        .src([
            './src/app/entry1.ts'
        ], { base: 'src' })
        .pipe(webpackStream(webpackConfig_Host, webpack))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'));
});
```